# VBA TextToColumns formats form 24hr to 12hr automatically

Tags: excel, vba

im currently dealing with a VBA issue. I want to split Date/Time into different Columns. The time is given in a 24hr format.

When i use the built-in Excel function everything works as intended and the 24hr format is kept. However, once i try the same code (recorded before) within VBA the time format is changed to 12hr and (that is the real issue) it uses another cell to add either "AM" or "PM". **Is there any way i can prevent Excel from doing that?**

I can change the Number Format of the desired range, that gives me the time in my desired 24hr format, but the next cell is still occupied by AM or PM (even though times like 13:xx:xx AM dont make much sense)

This is my code for the TextToColumn function:

```
    text.TextToColumns Destination:=text.Cells(1, -5), DataType:=xlDelimited _
            , TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Why not use formulas for that? Assuming `A1` contains the DateTime-value, you can for example use `=Trunc(A1)` for the Date and `=A1-Trunc(A1)` for the time.

Comment: I would like to use it as part of a bigger macro function and reuse the exact function several times. Also it should all work out of the box for the users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **Format** function. Based on my test, we can use the code resembles the following(Don't use hh:mm:ss directly, instead using the "hh:mm:ss t"/"hh:mm:ss tt" and what you like to replace the t/tt):

```
Sub Test()
Dim dTime As Date
Dim x As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim index As Integer

MsgBox ws.Rows.Count

x = 1

For index = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ' Sets the date in the cell of the first column
    Cells(x, 1).Value = Format(Cells(index, 3), "mm/dd/yyyy")

    ' Sets the time in the cell of the second column
    Cells(x, 2).Value = Format(Cells(index, 3), "hh:mm:ss t")

    x = x + 1
Next
End Sub
```